# Use jQuery grid instead of iterator in Struts 2 and Hibernate

Tags: jquery, hibernate, jsp, jqgrid, struts2

I have developed my WebApp  with Struts 2 & JPA and now I want  improve it  using jQuery Grid instead of iterator for showing all data from database.

I have in my JSP:

```jsp
<table class="userTable"   >
<tr class="even">
<th>ID</th>
<th>user name</th>                                  
<th>email</th>
<th>adress</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<s:iterator value="userlist"  status="userStatus">
<tr class="<s:if test="#userStatus.odd == true ">odd</s:if><s:else>even</s:else>">
<td><s:property value="user_ID" /></td>
<td><s:property value="namel" /></td>
<td><s:property value="email" /></td>
<td><s:property value="adress" /></td>
<td>
<s:url id="editURL" action="edituser">
<s:param name="user_ID" value="%{user_ID}"></s:param>
</s:url> <s:a href="%{editURL}"  title="Edit"></s:a>
                                
<s:url id="deleteURL" action="deleteuser">
<s:param name="user_ID" value="%{user_ID}"></s:param>
</s:url> <s:a href="%{deleteURL}"  title="delete" ></s:a>
</td>

</tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
```

And in my `struts.xml`  I have for example :

```xml
<package name="default" extends="hibernate-default">
  <action name="deleteuser" method="saveOrUpdate" class="com.userAction">
    <result name="success" type="redirect">/xxxx</result>
  </action>
</package>
<!-- and I have problem when I use this -->
<package name="default" extends="hibernate-default,struts-default,json-default" namespace="/">
</package>
```

in my class `Action` which communicates with class `UserDao` :

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User>{
private List<User> userlist = new ArrayList<User>();
//+ all method
}
```

Now  I want to know to implement this example to use jQuery grid.
I have already check this [GridTag](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag)  but I have some issue like trying use

```xml
 <package name="default" extends="hibernate-default,struts-default,json-default" namespace="/">
```

Comment: Does your DAOs implementation work with `hibernate-default`?

Comment: Yes this  `extends="hibernate-default"`  work  perfectly with CRUD operation but l have red that if i want to implement jQgrid i need to add this `extends="hibernate-default,struts-default,json-default"` but   does't  work with it.

Comment: The package `json-default` requires json plugin and json library to work with json result type.

Comment: I have already `json plugin` and i added ` json library` but when  i put this `<package name="default" extends="hibernate-default,struts-default,json-default"   >` my app not work i can't access to database with hibernate  i get this exception `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: `INFO: Server startup in 5365 ms
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.projet.struts.model.dao.UserDaoImpl.listUser(UserDaoImpl.java:105)
 at com.projet.struts.controle.action.CategorieAction.listAceuil(CategorieAction.java:39) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)at com.opensymphony.x 
`

Answer (score 0):

Whats your purpose of converting your html table to jqgrid? Just to display the data or you need to get some advantages of jqgrid like  sorting, search, pagination. If you need these advantages, what my suggestion is go for client side jqgrid implementation.

Initially i tried jqgrid plugin available from struts2 for my project. It seems we need manually handle the sorting, search, pagination. I wasted lot of time on manually doing this. Hope you got some ideas.

It is easy to implement jqgrid from client side, There is a useful jqgrid official link available for converting html table to jqgrid. [jQgrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). Under that New in version 3.3 - Html to grid. Let me know if this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

When you added packages `struts-default,json-default` you have overridden `default-interceptor-ref` configuration. You should explicitly define it in your `default` package

```
<default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStackHibernate"/>
```

Also, if you are using a convention plugin to map actions make sure you have 
`@ParentPackage("default")` annotation, or `<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="default"/>`